# Не запускаются JAR файлы.

Tags: jar, java

Ребят, помогите плз.
Создал программку, собрал Jar файл, делаю по нему двойной клик а он не запускается. 
Особенность в том что если запускать в ручную через cmd то все нормально. Если собирать wrapper-ом в exe.
Как сделать так чтобы JAR сам по себе открывался по двойному клику?

Comment: Прописывать в системе ассоциации на данный тип файлов. Как именно и какие зависит как минимум от вашей ОС. Если вы спрашиваете как юзер, то это вообще не на хэшкод. Если как программист, то проверять текущее ассоциации можно, например, в инсталляторе вашей программы и спрашивать юзера об их изменении, если они вас не устраивают.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Процитирую [ответ с SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9753103/897090)

> For Windows 7:
>
> 1. Start "Control Panel"
> 2. Click "Default Programs"
> 3. Click "Associate a file type or protocol with a specific program"
> 4. Double click .jar
> 5. Browse C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
> 6. Click the button Open
> 7. Click the button OK

Comment: В общем да, но не у всех Program Files называется именно так. Поэтому лучше `%PROGRAMFILES%\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe`. Это при условии, что Java стоит в каталоге по умолчанию, а не где-то ещё.

Comment: а можно както это дело "автоматизировать" ну в смысле зашить в сам jar чтоль?

Comment: @Expo1on если речь идёт о создании простого способа запуска *для пользователя*, то люди в таких случаях обычно пишут bat-файлы.
RUN_ME.bat

    %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -jar your.jar

Comment: спс, как доберусь до кода попробую.

Comment: @VladD А если стоит 10ка? Я там не нашел систему ассоциаций.

Comment: @антонсорокин: Вот тут должна быть:  `Win + I` + https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciCV4.png